# How do I delete empty rows in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have empty rows in SAS after I imported an `.xls` file.

I'm using the following code but it is not working.

I'm trying to delete all the empty rows.

```
DATA PROJECT.CLEAN_DATA1; 
set PROJECT.merged_data; 
  if missing(coalesceC(of _character_)) and missing(coalesce(of_numeric_)) then delete; 
run;
```

Please help!

Comment: How is it not working?  Is it keeping the empty rows? Generating an error? Make sure to have a space between the `of` keyword and the `_numeric_` variable list.  Are you sure the character variables are empty? Perhaps they have some non-printing character?

Comment: Unless you have empty rows throughout your data set that's overkill. You can usually pick a single column and delete based on that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete blank observations in a data set in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291756/how-to-delete-blank-observations-in-a-data-set-in-sas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: It was “character” in the original post with out “_”.

`_CHARACTER_` is the constant that includes all characters in SAS. Try that instead in the condition statement.

And it is a good programming practice to write global constants in SAS as is. So, the condition is -

```
missing(coalesceC(of _CHARACTER_)) and missing(coalesce(of _NUMERIC_))
```